# Ionic: Modal occupies more height than needed

Tags: css, user-interface, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

It seems that when the Modal is centered in screen it occupies more `height` than what is needed: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IHJ9k3?p=preview)

How to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Actually this is not an Issue. This will look normal on mobile device but, will create issues while viewing on desktop .

However, if you still want to solve this...remove min-height from `modal` class in `ionic.css` : 5298 line number.